# android firebase notifications works not

Tags: android, firebase, notifications

I set up the Firebase messaging with my app, but unfortunately the notifications are not coming.

I set up Firebase properly, it is connected to my app, I also sent some test messages, in the Firebase it says completed, however I did not receive them on my phone.

My app is not in the store yet, I am developing and testing it via Android studio.

Here is my MyFirebaseInstanceIDService class

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

/**
 * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
 * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
 * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
 */
// [START refresh_token]
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);


    // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}
// [END refresh_token]

/**
 * Persist token to third-party servers.
 *
 * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
 * maintained by your application.
 *
 * @param token The new token.
 */
private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    // Add custom implementation, as needed.
}
```

}

and here comes the MyFirebaseMessagingService class:

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

```
/**
 * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
 */
// [START receive_message]
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
    // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
    // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
    // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
    // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
    // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
    // messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
    // [END_EXCLUDE]


    //"Title","Message","NotyType",   "hotelStatus"

    String title = "";
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle() != null){
        title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    }

    String message = "";
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody() != null){
        message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
    }

    Log.e("notification","recieved");


    sendNotification(title, message);
    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
}
// [END receive_message]


private void sendNotification(String title, String body) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0 /* Request code */,
            i,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,
            getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(sound)
            .setContentIntent(pi);

    NotificationManager manager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    assert manager != null;
    manager.notify(0, builder.build());
} }
```

I don't see any logs when debugging, also don't receive any notifications on the phone.

Am I doing something wrong here? Can you please advice? Thanks.

Comment: Notifications are not coming when app is in background or no matter? If you didn't check that make sure you check that. If notifications are coming when your app is in front and not coming when app is in background  then there is solution to your issue.

Comment: "... testing it via Android studio". So you are not testing on a real device? Does emulator register a Token. Is your emulator connected to the net?

Comment: I am testing it on a real device, connected to my PC and through the Android Studio, but the notifications doesn't come even if the app is running normally neither in background (not sure what in background really means - logically I need the notifications, when the user has the app closed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onMessageReceived does not get called with a push sent with just notification tag and your app isn't in foreground. If it is indeed in foreground, your onMessageReceived will get called.

If you want your onMessageReceived to get triggered, you will need to send the push with an additional data tag or just the data tag.

However note, if you send both notification and data tags, your onMessageReceived will only get triggered if your app is in foreground, If it's in background, everything inside the data tag will be passed inside an click intent as extras

Only a Data tag will always call onMessageReceived regardless of whether you app is in foreground or not.

Eg: for just a data tag :)

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{ "data": {
    "score": "5x1",
    "time": "15:10"
  },
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
}
```

Comment: Sorry, had missed a clarification in the first line!!

Comment: Your correction has improved your answer. But in the second paragraph it is still not quite correct. It should read :: "If you want your onMessageReceived to always handle your messages, you will need to send the push with ONLY the `data` tag."  :: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: yea that's why i kept the third para... that points the details of the second para

Comment: lemme add the only data part, should be easier for the poor guy :)

Comment: Yes! That will help. Just wait until he gets around to the iOS equivalent of his app and discovers that Android and iOS handle FCM messages differently. ;)

Comment: Omg don't even get me started on the Ios part, that literally made me have my app only on android, the only data not getting delivered if app is not open/cached is pure retarded. I mean what's the point of a notification if it only gets delivered if the app is open. (I had a custom need that specifically needed only data tags... mechanism to bunch up data and process it before showing it)

Comment: Well thank you very much for explaining this, but how can I only send the data if I want to always call onMessageReceived? In Firebase console there is an advanced option where is KEY and VALUE. So I filled this in, but still the message text is mandatory. I tried to send it also to devices where my app is installed (only my device for now), I also tried to send it to single device with token, but nothing works. Can be the onTokenRefresh is not calling at all, so I have the wrong token? (I took it from firebase settings - server key)

Comment: Anything that you send from a console is always just a notification tag. For data, need to have your own server which can call the fcm send url as a post request with the body as described above

Comment: First three lines in the sample are: the url you need to call, the other two are request headers. Check out firebase page to know how to send from app server. Use the legacy docs as the new ones need oauth and i am pretty sure it's going to be too complicated for you right now

Comment: Strange, that with Firebase also did not receive any notification when my app was in foreground. OK, so there is not possible to send only data with Firebase, so I will try that from my server. But where to put that code please? Should I create a json file or js or how should I launch that code from my server? I tried to use the POSTMAN software to send data only, but it says Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send.

Comment: Did you use the headers? Keep it a post request, add the headers content-type and the authorization header... Keep your fcm api key from project settings here

Answer (score 1):

OH now I tried something! I updated my MyFirebaseMessagingService class as you see in my question now, and now it WORKS! From Firebase console I sent only message, no data, and all the notifications I received in my device! Even if my app is running, even if I closed it! Every notification I received. When the app was running, the notification has my custom icon, and when the app is closed, the default "bell" icon is there, but in both cases I received the notifications! Not sure how it is possible, but it works.